# Inject CSS file in HTML head by replacing <link> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm

I'm looking for a (npm-based?) solution that will simply replace:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
```

with

```html
<style><!-- actual contents of the style.css file here --></style>
```

as a simple build step to make a lightweight static website. I have found a ton of (often broken) packages that inline the CSS in every element in the DOM, which is *not* what I want.

My build pipeline looks like this:

1. Compile SASS (minified)
2. Minify HTML
3. *Inject minified CSS in HTML `<style>` tag*.

I'm looking for step three.

I tried following npm packages:

- `inlineCss`: does inline style into every element instead.
- `Styliner`: seems broken.

Comment: Why don't you create a python script that takes care of this?. It is fairly simple, given that you haven't found a tool that provides what you need. I'm working on it though, just for curiosity, will share if you want my solution. You could aggregate this to a docker image, and add it to a jenkins stage!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same requirement. Here's what I did. I'm using Gulp to:

1. Compile Sass files to CSS
2. Inject link tags into the HTML file so that I don't have to manually add it into the HTML file
3. Then with the help of these link tags, I get the href source of the CSS file,
   grab the contents of this CSS file and then inject the CSS files'
   contents into the HTML file replacing the original link tag.

Have a look at the full gulp file [here](https://github.com/ClydeDz/gulp-demo/blob/master/gulpfile.js). I execute this using the command `gulp build` which runs all of the above steps (line #37 of the file linked).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I worked my way around the issue by making a script that does this replacement very rudimentary; but it works:

**inline-css.js**:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const html = fs.readFileSync('dist/index.html', 'utf8');
const css = fs.readFileSync('dist/style.css', 'utf8');

const inlinedHtml = html.replace(
    '<link rel="stylesheet"href="style.css"type="text/css"charset="utf-8">',
    "<style>" + css + "</style>");

fs.writeFileSync('dist/index.inlined.html', inlinedHtml);
```

And then run it with `$ node inline-css.js`.

Comment: I was working on a solution that reads all .html in a directory (recursively), searched for ``<link>`` attributes and searched for css content of files that were located on ``href``. This avoids you knowing about the mappings html-css as they are already defined on the files. This code is not very scalable though, but as long as it works and suits for your needs perfect! :-)